# How to return 5 random "Powerball" numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, for-loop

Trying to return 5 random numbers between 1 and 42 in Java.

I currently have logic to return a single number (putting it into an ArrayList, but I'd like to do away with that.)  I'm stumped on implementation to return 5 random numbers.  Would I need 5 for loops?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
    }
```

I've seen some other related examples here and they seem more complex than what my needs dictate.  However, I could be wrong.

Comment: Almost there, just make an array to store more than one value in.

Comment: Your loop produces 10 random numbers that overwrite the value of local variable `r`.

Comment: Use `Random` class and `nextInt(int)` if you want to eliminate the slight bias in your current implementation.

Comment: Why does the loop need to be there? Anyways, r will disappear outside of the loop because of scope. You can remove the loop. Also, you don't need an `ArrayList`, you can use an `int[]` like this: `int[] nums = new int[5]`. Then, you can just have a for loop (5 times) that generates 5 random numbers and inserts them into the array: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) nums[i] = random.nextInt(42) + 1;` (Or `(int)(Math.random * 42) + 1;`

Comment: If you just wanted the numbers in a String, instead, you can have a `String powerball = "";` and in the for loop: `powerball += "" + (random.nextInt(42) + 1);

Answer (score 2):

Simply place each random number into an array and return the array...

```
public int[] powerBalls() {
     int[] balls = new int[5];
     for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
          balls[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 42) + 1;
     }
     return balls;
}
```

Comment: This answer (and all other) are wrong. Powerball can't have same number more than one time, right? In this implementation this can happen.

Comment: @WaleryStrauch While technically correct, that's not the question.  Gotta leave something for the OP to do ;)

Comment: @WaleryStrauch Then just add a while loop that runs while the new number is one of the old ones

Comment: @WaleryStrauch This is also the importance of asking a good question ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Set` to generate `5` **Unique Random** numbers.

```
Random random = new Random();
Set randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(randomNumbers.size()< 5) {
    randomNumbers.add(random.nextInt(42)+1);
}
```

Since you've mentioned that you're using an `ArrayList` which will hold all the random numbers, you could just add all the elements present in `randomNumbers` set to your `ArrayList`.

**Update:-**

To suit your needs, you need to do something like this:-

```
Random random = new Random();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
while(set.size()< 5) {
    set.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(42)+1));
}
fortuneList3.addAll(set);
```

Comment: I like this, and its close but I'm getting a compile error because I can't convert a Set to a String.

Comment: `Set` to a `String`? What are you trying to do with this set of random integers actually? Can you tell that?

Comment: This code lives in a get method which feeds a string (in an adjacent method a random string of words is returned) to a Swing GUI for display to the user.  I initially wrote the code to return a single random number (see code below) but am updating to have a lottery focus.

Comment: example of the original code with the int to string conversion:         fortuneList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
            String intString = Integer.toString(r);
            fortuneList3.add(new Fortune(intString));
        }

Comment: Check the update in my answer! See if that serves the purpose!

Comment: that did not work either, unfortunately.  I'm getting a compile error for `.addAll(set);` states no suitable method found.  This is in a class which implements another class, could that be part of the issue?  I really appreciate all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! Each number can be taken only one time. With your solution it is possible to get same number more than one time.

Other solution (and here you can't have same numer more than one time) is to create array with all numbers, shuffle it and take first 5:

```
public int[] powerBalls() {
  // create array with all numbers
  List<Integer> balls = new ArrayList<Integer>(42);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++)
    balls.add(i);

  // shuffle
  Collections.shuffle(balls);

  // take first 5
  int[] result = new int[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    result[i] = balls.get(i);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
IntArray = new int[5]; //Create an array
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        IntArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the numbers in array and return that array.

```
int []randArray;
randArray = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //for 5 random numbers
        randArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
    }

//now return this array "randArray"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a straight forward approach.

```
   List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {
              while(true)
              {
                 int r = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
                  if (!generated.contains(r))
                  {            
                      generated.add(r);
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my 2 cents in. I recently made a jQuery Plugin, appropriately named "Powerball". I'll share with ya the formula i'm using as well as link ya my plugin. Not sure why anyone would really need this. I did it just for fun! LoL!

### The Function

```
function getNumbers() {
    var a=[];   //  array to return
    for(i=1;5>=i;i++){  //  for loop to get first 5 numbers
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*59)+1; //  set #
        while (a.indexOf(b) > -1) { b = Math.floor(Math.random()*59)+1; }   //  reset # if already used
        a.push(b);  //  add number to array
    }
    a.push(Math.floor(35*Math.random())+1); //  add ball 6 number
    return a;   //  0 index array will have a length of 6, [0-4] being whiteball numbers, [5] being the red ball
}
```

### The Plugin

### jsFiddle

- Contains the plugin between comment lines
- Shows example use

Use is as easy as `$("element").powerball()`. However, only one method exist for it at the moment, `$("element").powerball("setNumbers")`. That method simply resets the numbers shown in the p tags.

- Style: a note!

  - All styling is done through a style tag added to the header upon initialization. This means there's no need for extra files to add, but it also gives the ease of custom styling. See more about styling in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/MJzVW/)!