# array with non repeating numbers from a range in ascending order, java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Im trying to generate an array with 1000 integers of non-repeating numbers in ascending order from 0 to 10,000

So far what I have is:

```
 public static void InitArray(int[] arr) { // InitArray method
     int i, a_num; // int declared
     Random my_rand_obj = new Random(); // random numbers

     for (i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) // for loop
     {
        a_num = my_rand_obj.nextInt(10000); // acquiring random numbers from 0 - 10000
            arr[i] = a_num; // numbers being put into array (previoulsy declared of size 1000)
     }

  }
public static void ShowArray(int[] arr) { // ShowArray method
     int i; // int declared
     for (i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) { // for loop
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); // show current array content
     }
     System.out.println(); // empty line
  }
public static void Sort(int[] arr) { // SortArray method
     int i, min, j; // int decalred
     for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { // for loop
        min = i; // min is i
        for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) { // nested for loop
           if (arr[j] < arr[min]) { // if statement
              min = j; // j is the new minimum
           }
        }       
        int swap = arr[min]; // swap "method"
        arr[min] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = swap;
     }  
  }
```

Is there any way to check the numbers are not repeating? Is there a function besides the random generator that will let me generate numbers without repeating? Thanks for any help

Comment: You can generate numbers simply by iterating over a for loop using the index - it would meet your requirements as stated.

Comment: If you want to be sure that there are non-repeating elements, convert your array to a HashSet, sort it and check its size vs the array's size.. (there are several other "efficient" methods as well.). BTW you are re-inventing the wheel .. Set allows only unique values, why not use it instead of array?

Comment: [How to generate random unique numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15916950/2024761) - This should be a decent read and probably you can then convert the `Set/List` to an array and sort it using `Arrays.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare array of size 10,000 
and init the array in away that each cell in the array will holds the value of it's index:

```
int [] arr= new  int[10000];
for (int i=0 i < arr.length; i++){
     arr[i] = i
}
```

Now you can shuffle the array using java Collections.
and take the first 1000 items from the array and sort then using java sort.

Comment: OP needs random nos. from `0-10,000` alright, but OP needs an array of size only `1,000`.

Comment: That is way he should take the first 1000 items as I mentions in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do I believe..

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
for(int i=0;i< arr.length;i++)
    hs.add(arr[i]);
List<Integer> integers=new ArrayList<>(hs);
Collections.sort(integers);
```

Comment: Not fair... I was just gonna write that! ;-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker LOL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A **very simple solution** is to generate the numbers cleverly. I have a solution. Though it may not have an *even distribution*, it's as simple as it can get. So, here goes:

```
public static int[] randomSortedArray (int minLimit, int maxLimit, int size) {
    int range    = (maxLimit - minLimit) / size;
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        array[i] = minLimit + rand.nextInt(range) + range * i;
    }
    return array;
}
```

So, in your case, call the method as:

```
int randomSortedArray = randomSortedArray(0, 10_000, 1_000);
```

It's very simple and doesn't require any sorting algorithm. It simply runs a single loop which makes it run in linear time (i.e. it is of [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) = `O(1)`).

As a result, you get a randomly generated, "pre-sorted" `int[]` (`int` array) in unbelievable time!

Post a comment if you need an explanation of the algorithm (though it's fairly simple).